# list comprehension python with if statement

Tags: list-comprehension

While trying to workout list comprehension , I got stuck with desired value repeated.

I have 2 lists: L1, L2. Result required is list of items from L2 if these items are smaller than/ equal to, at least one of the items in L1.

```
L1=[10,20,30,40,50]
L2=[3,11,51]
L3=[d2 for d2 in L2 for d1 in l1 if d2<=d1]
```

L3 is returned as [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 11, 11, 11, 11]

Answer contains valid items, but are repeated.
I know using set(), we can get rid of repetitions but may be I am using list-comprehension in a wrong way. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Loops to achieve the desired result would be:

```
L3=[]
for d2 in L2:
    for d1 in L1:
        if d2<=d1:
            L3.append(d2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from your expansion into loops, the inner loop runs over every element in `L1`, so the `d2` element will get appended once for **every** time there's a bigger element in `L2`.

You could use a `set()` (equivalently, `{ }` brackets as HepaKKes suggests) to get rid of repetitions, but this is inefficient -- you're still creating the unneeded intermediate results. It will be `O(n^2)` time.

You're selecting items based on whether they're `<=` than any item in `L1`. This is the same as asking whether they're `<= max(L1)`. So the following:

```
L3 = [e for e in L2 if e < max(L1)]
```

will achieve the same result. If you save the value of `L1` ahead of time

```
L1_max = max(L1)
L3 = [e for e in L2 if e < L1_max]
```

then this solution is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote goes through two nested for-loops, and whenever the condition `d2<=d1` is true, that value is appended. So we're seeing both `3` and `11` added for *each* value in L2 that they're less than.

Instead, you'll want a stricter condition for adding `d2` to `L3`, so that your comprehension can be of the form `L3 = [d2 for d2 in L2 if (x)]`, where `x` is equivalent to "`d2` is less than some value in `L1`". There are a few ways to do that, but I found the following to work:

```
L3 = [d2 for d2 in L2 if (filter(lambda d1: d2<=d1, L1))]
```

Comment: `filter` returns a list. I think you want to use `any`, as in: `if any(d2 <= d1 for d1 in L1)`. Map would also work.

Comment: ah, yup. `filter` works here because any non-empty list evaluates to `True`, but `any` would be cleaner.

Comment: oh, it does work. ha! (yeah, I would still use `any`).

Answer (score 1):

If the task is to write a single list comprehension, I would go for something like this:

```
In [22]: [x for x in L2 if any([y >= x for y in L1])]
Out[22]: [3, 11]
```